# Can I alternate between a common class in two different libraries based on menu command?

Tags: java, interface, jar

In learning mode here and playing around with Jar files.  Not sure if this is possible...

I have an application (Server) with 3 main parts:  Response, Request, and Router.  My Router was originally a class inside my Server.  Then I pulled it out and made it a separate Jar.  Got that to work.  Now I want to make multiple Jars and have the Server use one based on a menu command.  The server has two outside libraries (i.e., Jars) available (A & B).  Each is a custom Router class.

I want to write code in my server menu like this:

```
Server:  "Which router do you want to use?"
User:  "A"
*Server uses A's Router.*
```

or

```
Server:  "Which router do you want to use?"
User:  "B"
*Server uses B's Router*
```

Here's my Server run() method...

**Before trying to connect to multiple routers:**

```
public void run() {
    Request request = new Request();
    Router router = new Router();
    Response response = new Response();

    HashMap receivedRequest = request.get(Socket);
    byte[] builtResponse = router.getResponse(receivedRequest);
    response.send(Socket, builtResponse);
    Socket.close();
}
```

**My attempt (but not working):**

```
public void run() {
    Request request = new Request();
    Router router
    if "A"
      router = new A.Router(workingDirectory, publicDirectoryPath, routesFilePath, htAccessFilePath);
    else
      router = new B.Router(workingDirectory, publicDirectoryPath, routesFilePath, htAccessFilePath);
    Response response = new Response();

    HashMap receivedRequest = request.get(Socket);
    byte[] builtResponse = router.getResponse(receivedRequest);
    response.send(Socket, builtResponse);
    Socket.close();
}
```

Problem is that my "router" variable has to be declared a certain type (an A router or B router).  If I make an interface, then I have to implement the interface in each Jar and I can't do that, right?

Wondering if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I make an interface, then I have to implement the interface in each Jar and I can't do that, right?

Yes, you can do this. You can have a jar A that exposes the interface and another jar B that has the interface implementations and handle the behavior of the interfaces. Note that jar B depends of the presence of jar A to work.

Comment: I'm confused.  Wouldn't my interface need to be in Server?  And if it's in Server, how do I reference it in the two libraries (A and B).  I guess my question is where do I put the interface?

Comment: @Kelly the interfaces should go in the most generic place where they can be accessed through other libraries to implement them and clients to use them. If you're building your application in a framework perspective, then it would be good to add the interfaces in a jar. If you're building your application just to be used as client (console, GUI, web, mobile), then put the interfaces in your main jar.